# Set last column width as rest of the total parent's container width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to achieve 4 columns layout where I have dynamic text (small or a little big so not sure about width of them) for first 3 columns. I want 4th column width as rest of the width from the first 3 columns. For example, If parent container is of 200px and the first 3 columns content need 120px of it then my 4th column should automatically of 80px and I want to apply text-overflow in it.

I'm trying this with table but I'm stuck and not getting what to do. Here is my attempt - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bg60ssca/)

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td class="shrink">Dynamic text</td>
        <td class="shrink">Dynamic text</td>
        <td class="shrink">Dynamic text</td>
        <td class="expand">last column I should not wrap down or I should not go beyond the parent width.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I'm very new to `CSS3 flex` or `CSS3 Grid` but if this can be easily achieved with that then I would be happy to use it.

**UPDATE**

I want space between columns which is 5px for each column. This will be irrespective of text content. its long or short. Also, I don't want any content to drop down to next line so I will be using `white-space:nowrap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, playing  with the `font-size` property and the `first-line` pseudo-element. The original text is effectively still there, but you can't see it...

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12pt;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

table td.shrink {
  white-space: nowrap
}

table td.expand {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0.01em;
  word-break: break-all;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 100em;
}

table td.expand:first-line {
  font-size: 100em;
  float: left;
}

table td.expand:after {
  content: "\2026";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 1em;
  font-size: 100em;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 500px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="shrink">Dynamic text</td>
      <td class="shrink">Dynamic text</td>
      <td class="shrink">Dynamic text</td>
      <td class="expand">last column I should not wrap down or I should not go beyond the parent width.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Can you explain a bit about how font-size and first-line behaves in this case? If you put it in your answer then it would be great for others too.

Comment: What if last column is having small text then `...` should not appear

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you...

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid green;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width:100%;
}

table td {
    border: 1px solid green;
    max-width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

table td.shrink {
    width: 20%;
}
table td.expand {
    width: 40%;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 500px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td class="shrink">Dynamic text</td>
        <td class="shrink">Dynamic text</td>
        <td class="shrink">Dynamic text</td>
        <td class="expand">last column I should not wrap down or I should not go beyond the parent width.</td>
    </tr>
   
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if in my first column there is text as `AND` which is only 3 character so there will be too much space between first and second column which I don't want again. so this won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the width to container, table and first three columns, then automatically the last column will assume the remaining portion of the container. Here is a working sample. I hope this is what you are looking for.

```css
.container {
    width: 1000px;
}

.container table {
    width: 100%;
}

.container table tr td {
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}

.container table tr td.shrink {
    /*width: 120px;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="shrink">Dynamic text</td>
            <td class="shrink">Dynamic text</td>
            <td class="shrink">Dynamic text</td>
            <td class="expand">last column I should not wrap down or I should not go beyond the parent width.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know how much content I will have in first 3 columns so I can't set width to them. I do so then the space between columns will increase that I don't want. I want to display a simple text line in column format so there won't be any border in it.

Comment: If you are not planning to add any fixed width in the table, you can remove the width parameter in .container table tr td.shrink. I have added the border jist for the visibility only you can remove that as well